# Order by shortestPath WITHOUT excluding disconnected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to implement a "find your friends" feature in my social graph, and to make it as user-friendly as possible I want to order the results of my query by shortest path (so that someone already in your "circle of friends" will show up first).  However, results that you dont yet have any relationship with (i.e. there is no shortest path to them) should still be included, in case the person you are looking for is someone totally disconnected from your current network.

My current query is (if the user had typed in 'Bill'):

```
MATCH (u:User), (me:User), path=shortestPath((me)-[:WORKED_ON]-(u))
WHERE u.first_name =~ '(?i)Bill.*'
OR u.last_name =~ '(?i)Bill.*' AND
me.user_id='someuserid1234'
RETURN u, path
ORDER BY LENGTH(path) ASC
```

This accomplishes the 'order by shortest path' but it excludes any disconnected nodes from the result.

Is there a way to say "order by shortest path, unless there is no path in which case use a path length of 20" perhaps?
Or maybe "order by shortest path, but if there are fewer than X results, ignore shortest path"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an OPTIONAL MATCH for the path between the nodes:

```
MATCH (u:User), (me:User)
WHERE u.first_name =~ '(?i)Bill.*'
OR u.last_name =~ '(?i)Bill.*' AND
me.user_id='someuserid1234'
OPTIONAL MATCH path=shortestPath((me)-[:WORKED_ON*]-(u))
RETURN u, coalesce(LENGTH(path), 20) as distance
ORDER BY distance ASC
```